# MySql delays/discards UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I am using MySQL 5.5 as the database for an EclipseLink-based persistence backend to a web app. The web app is built using Wicket 1.5 on Java 7. Testing environment runs on Jetty 7/Mac OSX Lion, production environment on Tomcat 6/Red Hat Enterprise 6.1.

This is what happens: On the web app, a light-weight cms, after executing a number of write operations, the write operations start being delayed or discarded. Reading the query log shows that somehow, these operations are not executed at once (even if I do all the transaction commits explicitly in the code), but later on, triggered by another write operation, suddenly older write ops are executed (in a single transaction). Note that they are not necessarily executed in order (maybe a threading issue?).

The error happens earlier in the production environment than in the testing environment, but it does happen in both, eventually. It only happens when I use the MySql database, and not with an in-memory H2 database I use for unit testing my code. I started out thinking it was an issue with Tomcat somehow caching form submits but since in the Jetty test env I could reproduce the problem I focussed on MySQL in stead.

Now I am by no means a MySQL expert, but I tried some fiddling with the query_cache system variables to no avail. I also hoped maybe setting flush=on would help, but it did not.

The question I have based on the above is if this is indeed a MySQL issue or do I have to check someplace else? And if so, can anybody point out what is going wrong? Maybe this is a rather broad question but if any part of it rings a bell with someone it would really be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I included a part of the EclipseLink log. As I can see, Thread …-20,5 uses UoW …7099 for all its work. Then for some reason it switches to Thread …-17,5. That thread requests the new UoW …1848. So far so good, but then at the end of this excerpt EL actually assigns the persists operation to …7099, while committing …1848. Note that I do not explicitly request UoWs in my code, I only use the EntityManager. Below the log you can also find the persistence.xml.

**EclipseLink Log**

```
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.113--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--persist() operation called on: NewsItem(id=0, header=7, content=7, timeStamp=2012-07-10T14:52:16.113+02:00).
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.114--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--assign sequence to the object (258 -> NewsItem(id=0, header=7, content=7, timeStamp=2012-07-10T14:52:16.113+02:00))
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.114--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--begin unit of work commit
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.115--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(NewsItem(id=258, header=7, content=7, timeStamp=2012-07-10T14:52:16.113+02:00))
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.115--ServerSession(1463061321)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.116--ClientSession(1223119569)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--begin transaction
[EL Fine]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.116--ClientSession(1223119569)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--INSERT INTO NEWSITEM (ID, CONTENT, HEADER, TIMESTAMP) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [258, 7, 7, 10 juli 2012 14:52]
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.118--ClientSession(1223119569)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--commit transaction
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.118--ServerSession(1463061321)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.119--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--end unit of work commit
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.119--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--resume unit of work
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.12--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Execute query ReportQuery(referenceClass=NewsItem sql="SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM NEWSITEM")
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.12--ServerSession(1463061321)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Fine]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.12--ServerSession(1463061321)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM NEWSITEM
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.122--ServerSession(1463061321)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.122--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Execute query ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=NewsItem sql="SELECT ID, CONTENT, HEADER, TIMESTAMP FROM NEWSITEM ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC")
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.122--ServerSession(1463061321)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Fine]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.122--ServerSession(1463061321)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--SELECT ID, CONTENT, HEADER, TIMESTAMP FROM NEWSITEM ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:52:16.124--ServerSession(1463061321)--Connection(1934751546)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-20,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:59:32.322--ServerSession(1463061321)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-17,5,main])--client acquired: 1003847240
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:59:32.322--ClientSession(1003847240)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-17,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 1029031848
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:59:32.322--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-17,5,main])--persist() operation called on: NewsItem(id=0, header=8, content=8, timeStamp=2012-07-10T14:59:32.322+02:00).
[EL Finest]: 2012-07-10 14:59:32.323--UnitOfWork(1257127099)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-17,5,main])--assign sequence to the object (259 -> NewsItem(id=0, header=8, content=8, timeStamp=2012-07-10T14:59:32.322+02:00))
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:59:32.323--UnitOfWork(1029031848)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-17,5,main])--begin unit of work commit
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:59:32.323--UnitOfWork(1029031848)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-17,5,main])--end unit of work commit
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:59:32.323--UnitOfWork(1029031848)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-17,5,main])--resume unit of work
[EL Finer]: 2012-07-10 14:59:32.324--UnitOfWork(1029031848)--Thread(Thread[qtp1629549850-17,5,main])--release unit of work
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="mySqlJpaPu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxx" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx" />
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Have you tried taking a few thread dumps and seeing if there are slow threads? One line of thinking here could be that the transfer between your app and mysql will be slower then an in memory Db and if you have any synchronized code it could be blocking. Which in turn looks like your writes are delayed, when in fact your code hasnt sent the request yet

Comment: @Sean I did not inspect the thread dumps themselves (yet) but MySQL is working on a one-thread-per-connection basis, so I would expect all the writes being done in sequence on that thread. Or are you talking about the threads in the jetty/tomcat?

Comment: from the application layer. so yea from jetty/Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt this is an issue with the MySQL database. Rather, I suspect it's an issue with the EclipseLink interaction with the transaction manager. You didn't mention whether you are using an external transaction manager (JTA or OTS).

When the UnitOfWork `commit` method is called, that should be causing changes to be applied to the database. That's true, unless the UnitOfWork is a child of a parent UnitOfWork. For a child UnitOfWork, the `commit` method does NOT apply changes to the database; it instead passes any changes to its parent UnitOfWork.

If it were my code, I would be inspecting it to verify that I wasn't dealing with nested units of work. I would verify that the calls to the acquireUnitOfWork method are on the session object, rather than on another UnitOfWork object.

Comment: All the stuff I do is rather straight-forward CRUD, i.e., I am never touching the UnitOfWork objects in my code. And if this would be the issue, would it not happen right from the start in stead after an arbitrary number of writes? I do not use an external transaction manager. Would that make a difference here?

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging in EclipseLink and inspect the log.  Do the transaction appear correct in the log, are the writes part of the transaction that you expect?

What type of connection pooling and transaction control are you using?  Include your persistence.xml.

How are you creating your EntityManagers (I assume you are using JPA?).  It sounds like you are sharing the same EntityManager with different threads/requests.  Each thread/request/transaction should have its own EntityManager.

Comment: Yep, it's EclipseLink JPA. I enabled the logs, and I was able to see what goes wrong, but I do not know (yet) why. I have added the log to the original question.

Comment: Create a new EntityManager for each thread and pass it around.  You should never be using an EntityManager or transaction as a singleton.  If you are desperate, you could use a ThreadLocal to store your persistence context.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting your EntityManagers and starting/commiting the transaction?  It looks like you might be obtaining a new EntityManager and using it to begin/commit a transaction rather than the one you have made the changes with.